# What are some communities with a similar concept to this site, but in a discussion format?

Tags: discussion

When I found this stack exchange site I was excited to start using it, but a lot of what I'm interested in is better suited toward a **discussion format** rather than a q / a format. I'd like to talk about the profession of software development at a high level, but I'm looking to talk about grey issues, and not just solutions to specific problems.

I've done some searching around the internet and most developer specific forums seem to have a focus on technical issues that people are experiencing. While they will allow meta type discussions discussion rarely happens.

The only alternative I've found is on forums that aren't programmer-centric, but which have an excess of developers who occasionally talk programming. That can be insightful, but rarely has much depth.

So is there anything out there like what I'm looking for?

Comment: Perhaps some of the programming related subreddits can hit that mix of fast moving, atomized content but yet a bit more discussion and less heavy-handed admins.

Comment: Quora has some great discussions.  Also if you want a more limited discussion our chat feature here is great for that too.

Comment: [reddit.com/r/askprogrammers](http://www.reddit.com/r/askprogrammers)?